# Upgrading Angular in 2022

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

I read https://update.angular.io/?v=12.0-13.0
So in Visual Studio

> `npx @angular/cli@13 update @angular/core@13 @angular/cli@13`

All looks good, but I am confused by various versions listed in various places.

`> ng v`

Shows

```
...
Angular CLI: 13.2.3
Node: 14.18.0
Package Manager: npm 6.14.15
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 13.2.2
... animations, cdk, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, material, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1302.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular   13.2.3
@angular-devkit/core            12.1.4
@angular-devkit/schematics      12.1.4
@angular/cli                    13.2.3
@schematics/angular             12.1.4
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.5.5
```

Hmm, I guess all those 12 are okay, but I don't know.  Are they?  Should I upgrade and how do I upgrade them?

But if I try

```
> npm outdated -g
Package       Current   Wanted  Latest  Location
@angular/cli   12.2.4  12.2.16  13.2.3  global
```

Outside of Visual Studio I'm told ng is using a version 12.

```
> ng v
Angular CLI: 12.2.4
[...]
Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.1202.4 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/core         12.2.4 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics   12.2.4 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular          12.2.4 (cli-only)
```

Why does two different `ng v` commands and `npm outdated` appear to differ (or maybe my understanding of the ng v isn't correct) and what might I do to straighten these things out so I can use all the latest stuff?

Answer (score 1):

You can have two different versions in two places (the local project and globally), and that is normal.

The reason is that you have installed Angular once globally (The version which is displayed when you run **ng v** anywhere, but the local project) and when you create a new project with **ng new** the global version will be taken, but will have separate node_modules which is local for just the new project created.

Now if you update the version in the project you have created, that will update only the local version for that project, the global Angular version will remain the same.

In order to update the global version, you can achieve with the same command but just with **-g** as an argument.

And the answer to your latest question:

**ng v** run outside of the local project gives the same results as **npm outdated -g** - consider the global version.

**ng v** run inside the local project should give the same results as **npm outdated** run inside the local project - consider the local project version.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.
I'm not sure I understand how to move forward.
All I'm trying to do is use the latest of everything.  I don't think I am trying to do anything tricky,
But npm update respects package.json
What command(s) do I use to get everything latest as possible, then test it and if it runs I'll merge the branch?

Comment: If you want also the global version to be up-to-date, just run the following commands: **npm uninstall -g @angular/cli** and 
**npm install -g @angular/cli@latest**
You may need sudo in front of it if you are using Linux.

The rest is completely fine, if your app works fine you can merge it. In order to test the app, run with **ng serve** and click around, also you can try **ng build --prod** to check if the build will be successfull. You can also consider running the unit or e2e tests too (if you have any) in order to confirm them too.

Comment: BUT NOTHING IS UP TO DATE.  Everything is only believing the specifications in **package.json** which limits it to major  ^M.m.p limits specified in **package.json**

I started with command which I was reading angular documentation.

`npx @angular/cli@13 update @angular/core@13 @angular/cli@13`

but only got to high V12.  

Is **uninstall** and **install** the only what to go forward past a major revision level?

I have 21 application packages and 3 global packages that are 1 or more Major versions behind, 

I don't really understand a systematic way to get try them all up to date.

Comment: I don't understand how you have concluded that it only goes to high v12. As I can see from your original question, you have updated your local project application version to 13. The only thing which remains is the global one. Please read again my comments, did you try running **npm uninstall -g @angular/cli and npm install -g @angular/cli@latest** ?

Comment: `npm outdated -g` 

shows nothing to be outdated!  (We won't go into a side problem I had where somehow I corrupted my npm installation and had to reinstall).

Now I have to figure out what to do about 20 local packages which are out of date when I do ...

`npm outdated`

I think I'll start a new question for that.  Thank you for your help.